# 406 ActionController::UnknownFormat on a POST on users [Devise] [Rails API]

Tags: api, post, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5.0.0.1
Ruby 2.3.0p0

I am trying to build a CRUD Rails API and I am having trouble with doing a POST. I am using devise gem for user management. Am I missing something here ?

When I try to create a POST thorugh Postman, I get the following response

```
{
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "exception": "#<ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat>",
    "traces": {
    "Application Trace": [],
    "Framework Trace": [
    {
        "id": 0,
    "trace": "responders (2.3.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:207:in `respond_with'"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
    "trace": "devise (4.2.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:32:in `create'"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
    "trace": "actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
    "trace": "actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'"
    },
    .....
}
```

Log looks like this

```
Started POST "/users/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-19 02:37:15 -0400
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"email"=>"gabanimillin@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

    responders (2.3.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:207:in `respond_with'
devise (4.2.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:32:in `create'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
.....
```

As far as I can see, my code in user_controller should work

app/controllers/api/v1/user_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      render json: user, status: 201, location: [:api, user]
    else
      render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

config/routes.rb

```
require 'api_constraints'  

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
# Api definition
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, :only => [:show, :create]
    end
  end
end
```

My spec file looks like

spec/controllers/api/v1

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller do
  before(:each) { request.headers['Accept'] = "application/vnd.traveltime_test.v1"}

  describe "GET #show" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
      get :show, params: {id: @user.id}, format: :json
    end

    it "returns the information about a reporter on a hash" do
      user_response = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
      expect(user_response[:email]).to eql @user.email
    end

    it "respond is successful" do
      expect(response.status).to eql 200
    end
  end

  describe "POST #create" do
    before(:each) do
      @user_attributes = FactoryGirl.create :user
      post :create, {user: @user_attributes}, format: :json
    end

    it "returns json body for the user just created" do

    end

  end
end
```

This is what I get once I run the test

```
F

Failures:

    1) Api::V1::UsersController POST #create returns json body for the user just created
Failure/Error: params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)

NoMethodError:
    undefined method `permit' for "1":String
       Did you mean?  print
     # ./app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:19:in `user_params'
     # ./app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'
# /Users/GabBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:33:in `block in process'
# /Users/GabBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:100:in `catch'
# /Users/GabBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:100:in `_catch_warden'
# /Users/GabBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:33:in `process'
# ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.05922 seconds (files took 1.18 seconds to load)
3 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

           rspec ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:28 # Api::V1::UsersController POST #create returns json body for the user just created
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your POSTMAN parameters.
You posted:

```
{ "email" => "email", "password" => "password }
```

Whereas the your controller expects the following params:

```
{ "user" => { "email" => "email", "password" => "password" } }
```

As described by your params sanitizer:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

Answer (score 1):

change it

`before(:each) do
   @user_attributes = FactoryGirl.create :user
   post :create, {user: @user_attributes}, format: :json
 end`

for this

`before(:each) do
   @user_attributes = FactoryGirl.create :user
   post :create, params: {user: @user_attributes}, format: :json
 end`